# Custom Highlighting/Markers of java annotations using xtext (Extending java syntax highlighting)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, xtext

I need to highlight or create markers on some annotations using meta information, which I'm reading from a database. I've already implemented a solution using markers, but I need to take care by myself about the whole marker lifecycle and it doesn't work on the fly. Is there a way to extend the highlighting of JDT using XText?

I'm not sure if xtext is the right solution for my purpose. So if there are other frameworks, I would be glad to hear about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Xtext is the right solution if you want to extend your Java editor. Basically, you have to manage your markers lifecycle on your own.

I suggest registering a [builder](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html) for Java projects - that gets called every time your java files are changed, which seems appropriate for adding/removing markers as needed.